# Redirecting mobile users from root/[x] to root/mobile/[x] using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mobile

I'm using the following code to redirect mobile users:

```
#mobile redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera     mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
```

Thing is, this redirects every page to the main page, e.g accessing www.site.com/folder/page with a mobile device will redirect to www.site.com/mobile. I'd like to edit the code so the same page will lead to www.site.com/mobile/folder/page, and I need this rule to apply for any page mobile users will try to reach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
#mobile redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera     mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you also tell me how do I exclude files from this rule? Say I wanna same.php be used by both mobile and desktop users?